# Edittext at the bottom of a listview is hidden by softkeyboard

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

I have an EditText at the bottom of my ListView. When I tap the EditText the softkeyboard pops up as expected while the listview slides up placing the EditText above the keyboard. However, once I begin typing, the ListView slides back down and the EditText is now behind the softkeyboard obstructing the view of the typing. I am still able to type, but the EditText is covered by the softkeyboard.

How can I keep the EditText visible above the keyboard?

PS. I am using adjustPan

EDIT: Here is a link to someone with the same issue I am facing but I don't see the solution:
http://developer.samsung.com/forum/thread/issue-while-entering-the-data-in-a-list-with-edit-texts/202/244386?boardName=General&startId=zzzzz~

Comment: edittext is the last item in your listview or is it an independent view ??

Comment: Have you tried with `adjustResize` in your manifest file.

Comment: Can you post your screen shot ? Are you trying to say that edittext is getting hide as the softkeyboard opens ?

Comment: A view containing an EditText is the last view in the listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so this problem is only present on Samsung devices. I guess it's an issue with their touchwiz interface. I was not able to find a real fix, but I worked around the issue by adding a blank textview underneath the last EditText in the ListView. The blank TextView has to be tall enough to allow the EditText to jump higher than the softkeyboard. It's a workaround, but it works for my application.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

Change in the Manifest file

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Some times it you tap to EditText, Keyboard not getting pop-up, so for explicitly Pop-up keyboard use this

```
 editText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    InputMethodManager m = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    if (m != null) {
                        m.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
                        editText.requestFocus();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Or You can have a look on

**TreeObserver** and **GlobalLayoutListener**

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Since it is in a ListView the EditText is not always on screen. Where do I set the Listener? During OnCreate there is not an EditText displayed yet.